# Failed to load class slf4g StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

I don't know what is the problem with the program. I got this notice. I have set the dependencies correctly on pom.xml file.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

pom.xml

```
..
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency> 
..
```

Comment: Can you please provide your system information and which IDE you are using.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to avoid this warning is to add the following runtime dependency to your project's POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will provide a simple logging implementation that will print your INFO level statements. You'll quickly outgrow this solution, but it allows time to investigate the logging framework your code will  eventually use.

[SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) is a framework designed to hide the details of how your logging is actually implemented. For example at runtime you could decide to use [log4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html), [commons logging](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html), [Java logging](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) or [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).

## Update 1: How to reproduce the problem

The following Java project reproduces your issue:

```
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- java
            `-- HelloWorld.java
```

Run program from Maven as follows:

```
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=HelloWorld
..
..
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Once you add the missing dependency into your POM, your program will then have a logging implementation, which it can use to issue it's logging statements as follows:

```
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=HelloWorld
..
..
[HelloWorld.main()] INFO HelloWorld - Java says: Hello world
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### pom.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myspotontheweb.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### HelloWorld.java

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HelloWorld {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    public String speak(String speech) {
        log.info("Java says: {}", speech);

        return speech;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();

        hello.speak("Hello world");
    }
}
```

## Update 2: How to create an executable jar

If you configure Maven to create an executable jar then it will automatically package the jar with a classpath referencing the dependencies listed in your POM file.

```
$ mvn clean package
$ java -jar target/my-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[main] INFO HelloWorld - Java says: Hello world
```

### pom.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myspotontheweb.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>HelloWorld</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for brief information, but i tried your suggestion without any advantage !

Comment: @HatemSalem What kind of Java application are you writing? I think you need to supply some more details of how you are running your application. You are missing this jar from your classpath at runtime. If you are not running it from within Maven, perhaps it's missing from your packaged application?

Comment: @HatemSalem I've updated my answer with an example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @HatemSalem Second update is an example of how to package your jar files dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You only have the API. Provide an implementation.

Comment: I meant what Mark O'Connor wrote in more detail. He suggests using the simple implementation.

Answer (score -1):

It seems slf4j jars are missing in your class path. Download [slf4j libraries](http://www.slf4j.org/dist/slf4j-1.7.2.tar.gz) and add it in your project class path.

Comment: How come ? I bring them using maven !

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. Downloading tar packages is not how missing jars are added to a Maven project

Comment: @MarkO'Connor it contains required jars ( slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar), I mentioned to add them in class path. Sorry if i'm wrong