# Weblogic Maven Deploy

Tags: maven, weblogic

I am using `weblogic 10.3.6.0` and `maven 3`. I want to deploy my project to weblogic server with maven plugin. I do same steps in [this oracle documents](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13702/maven_deployer.htm)

But when I build my project, I get this error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JBoss Portlet Bridge - JSF 2 Basic Portlet 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy (default-cli) @ TestWeblogic ---
[WARNING] The POM for weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6 is missing, no dependency i  information available
[WARNING] The POM for weblogic:webservices:jar:10.3.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.446s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 01 16:50:02 EEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy (  (default-cli) on project TestWeblogic: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5:deploy failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6, weblogic:webservices:jar:10.3.6: Failure to find weblogic:weblogic:jar:10.3.6 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced ->        [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

My pom xml is here

```xml
<plugin> 
  <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId> 
  <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>10.3.6.0</version> 
  <configuration> 
      <adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</adminurl>
      <user>username</user> 
      <password>password</password> 
      <upload>true</upload> 
      <action>deploy</action> 
      <remote>false</remote> 
      <verbose>true</verbose> 
      <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source> 
     <name>${project.build.finalName}</name> 
  </configuration> 
 </plugin>
```

I use `weblogic server 10.3.6.0`, `eclipse juno` , `maven  3.0.4`.

Comment: This might be helpful,all steps are explained well. http://buttso.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-weblogic-prefix-with-weblogic.html

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668784/failed-to-load-class-slf4g-staticloggerbinder This same question has been asked so many times

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp  my problem not about SL4J. It is about deploy to weblogic server.

Answer (score 6):

You need to import `wlfullclient.jar` and `webservices.jar`.  I tried importing the `weblogic.jar` first, but maven threw a `ClassCastException` by `weblogic.utils.Debug`.
To build this client you need to execute:  `java -jar wljarbuilder.jar`  inside the `WL_HOME/server/lib`.

Once you are ready, import into the maven repository by executing the following commands:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=weblogic -DartifactId=weblogic
-Dversion=10.3.6  -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=wlfullclient.jar


mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=weblogic -DartifactId=webservices -Dversion=10.3.6  -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=webservices.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using JBoss, not Weblogic based on your logs:

```
Building JBoss Portlet Bridge
```